# Can't define view in plugin.xml via perspectiveExtensions

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

**NOTE**

Exceptions in previous versions were caused by the fact that plug-in id was ending with a number. This is probably not possible in Eclipse RCP.

**UPDATED VERSION**

I am trying to display a View by defining perspective extension in `plugin.xml`.

Here is may `plugin.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         id="application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application>
         <run
               class="try_03_eclipseplugin.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
      <perspectiveExtension
            targetID="*">
         <view
               id="try_03_eclipseplugin.SampleView"
               minimized="false"
               ratio="0.20"
               relationship="left"
               relative="org.eclipse.ui.editorss">
         </view>
      </perspectiveExtension>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <view
            allowMultiple="false"
            class="try_03_eclipseplugin.SampleView"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            id="try_03_eclipseplugin.SampleView"
            name="Sample View">
      </view>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            class="try_03_eclipseplugin.Handler"
            commandId="Try_03_EclipsePlugin.command1">
      </handler>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
         <command
               commandId="Try_03_EclipsePlugin.command1"
               label="Try"
               style="push">
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

And here is entire code for `Application` class (all advisors are made as inner classes):

```
    package try_03_eclipseplugin;

import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication;
import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplicationContext;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.eclipse.ui.application.IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer;
import org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor;
import org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor;

/**
 * This class controls all aspects of the application's execution
 */
public class Application implements IApplication {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication#start(org.eclipse.equinox.app.
     * IApplicationContext)
     */
    public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
        try {

            int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor());

            /*
            int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, new WorkbenchAdvisor() {
                @Override
                public WorkbenchWindowAdvisor createWorkbenchWindowAdvisor(IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer) {
                    return new WorkbenchWindowAdvisor(configurer) {
                        public void preWindowOpen() {
                            IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
                            configurer.setInitialSize(new Point(400, 300));
                            configurer.setShowCoolBar(false);
                            configurer.setShowStatusLine(false);
                            configurer.setTitle("Hello RCP"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                        }
                    };
                }

                @Override
                public String getInitialWindowPerspectiveId() {
                    return null;
                }

            });
            */

            if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART)
                return IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;
            else
                return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
        } finally {
            display.dispose();
        }
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication#stop()
     */
    public void stop() {
        if (!PlatformUI.isWorkbenchRunning())
            return;
        final IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
        final Display display = workbench.getDisplay();
        display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (!display.isDisposed())
                    workbench.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code of `SampleView` is following:

```
package try_03_eclipseplugin;


import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.*;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.*;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.ui.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;


/**
 * This sample class demonstrates how to plug-in a new
 * workbench view. The view shows data obtained from the
 * model. The sample creates a dummy model on the fly,
 * but a real implementation would connect to the model
 * available either in this or another plug-in (e.g. the workspace).
 * The view is connected to the model using a content provider.
 * <p>
 * The view uses a label provider to define how model
 * objects should be presented in the view. Each
 * view can present the same model objects using
 * different labels and icons, if needed. Alternatively,
 * a single label provider can be shared between views
 * in order to ensure that objects of the same type are
 * presented in the same way everywhere.
 * <p>
 */

public class SampleView extends ViewPart {

    /**
     * The ID of the view as specified by the extension.
     */
    public static final String ID = "try_03_eclipseplugin.SampleView";

    private TableViewer viewer;
    private Action action1;
    private Action action2;
    private Action doubleClickAction;

    /*
     * The content provider class is responsible for
     * providing objects to the view. It can wrap
     * existing objects in adapters or simply return
     * objects as-is. These objects may be sensitive
     * to the current input of the view, or ignore
     * it and always show the same content 
     * (like Task List, for example).
     */

    class ViewContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider {
        public void inputChanged(Viewer v, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
        }
        public void dispose() {
        }
        public Object[] getElements(Object parent) {
            return new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };
        }
    }
    class ViewLabelProvider extends LabelProvider implements ITableLabelProvider {
        public String getColumnText(Object obj, int index) {
            return getText(obj);
        }
        public Image getColumnImage(Object obj, int index) {
            return getImage(obj);
        }
        public Image getImage(Object obj) {
            return PlatformUI.getWorkbench().
                    getSharedImages().getImage(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_ELEMENT);
        }
    }
    class NameSorter extends ViewerSorter {
    }

    /**
     * The constructor.
     */
    public SampleView() {
    }

    /**
     * This is a callback that will allow us
     * to create the viewer and initialize it.
     */
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        viewer.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());
        viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());
        viewer.setSorter(new NameSorter());
        viewer.setInput(getViewSite());

        // Create the help context id for the viewer's control
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(viewer.getControl(), "Try_EclipsePlugin_03.viewer");
        makeActions();
        hookContextMenu();
        hookDoubleClickAction();
        contributeToActionBars();
    }

    private void hookContextMenu() {
        MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager("#PopupMenu");
        menuMgr.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
        menuMgr.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {
            public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager) {
                SampleView.this.fillContextMenu(manager);
            }
        });
        Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(viewer.getControl());
        viewer.getControl().setMenu(menu);
        getSite().registerContextMenu(menuMgr, viewer);
    }

    private void contributeToActionBars() {
        IActionBars bars = getViewSite().getActionBars();
        fillLocalPullDown(bars.getMenuManager());
        fillLocalToolBar(bars.getToolBarManager());
    }

    private void fillLocalPullDown(IMenuManager manager) {
        manager.add(action1);
        manager.add(new Separator());
        manager.add(action2);
    }

    private void fillContextMenu(IMenuManager manager) {
        manager.add(action1);
        manager.add(action2);
        // Other plug-ins can contribute there actions here
        manager.add(new Separator(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));
    }

    private void fillLocalToolBar(IToolBarManager manager) {
        manager.add(action1);
        manager.add(action2);
    }

    private void makeActions() {
        action1 = new Action() {
            public void run() {
                showMessage("Action 1 executed");
            }
        };
        action1.setText("Action 1");
        action1.setToolTipText("Action 1 tooltip");
        action1.setImageDescriptor(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().
            getImageDescriptor(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJS_INFO_TSK));

        action2 = new Action() {
            public void run() {
                showMessage("Action 2 executed");
            }
        };
        action2.setText("Action 2");
        action2.setToolTipText("Action 2 tooltip");
        action2.setImageDescriptor(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().
                getImageDescriptor(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJS_INFO_TSK));
        doubleClickAction = new Action() {
            public void run() {
                ISelection selection = viewer.getSelection();
                Object obj = ((IStructuredSelection)selection).getFirstElement();
                showMessage("Double-click detected on "+obj.toString());
            }
        };
    }

    private void hookDoubleClickAction() {
        viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {
            public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
                doubleClickAction.run();
            }
        });
    }
    private void showMessage(String message) {
        MessageDialog.openInformation(
            viewer.getControl().getShell(),
            "Sample View",
            message);
    }

    /**
     * Passing the focus request to the viewer's control.
     */
    public void setFocus() {
        viewer.getControl().setFocus();
    }
}
```

I expect view will appear immediately after program run. But it does not happen.

Simultaneously, I have a code to show new instance of a view with menu command -- and it works and shows view and even icon is shown.

Comment: You are referencing the Java perspective - have you include the JDT plugins so that this is available?

Comment: Sorry, it was parasitic trace. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This was because of the absence of perspective id.

When defined perspective factory

```
package try_03_eclipseplugin;

import org.eclipse.ui.IPageLayout;
import org.eclipse.ui.IPerspectiveFactory;

public class PerspectiveFactory implements IPerspectiveFactory {

    public static final String ID = "Try_03_EclipsePlugin.perspective"; 

    @Override
    public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    }

}
```

and described it in `plugin.xml` and then returned it's id in advisor:

```
@Override
                public String getInitialWindowPerspectiveId() {
                    return PerspectiveFactory.ID;
                    //return "org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective";
                }
```

it started to show initial view.

Still don't understand why it does not work with the ID of resource perspective (commented).